# Add-on in blender 2.8 not installing

Tags: add-on

[image]I am a newbie to Blender, and I want to export a house I made to unreal. To do this I am trying to download an add-on, but the addons will not install.

I have tried several different add ons, I tried dropping the addons straight into the add-on menu, I tried looking for a separate add-on folder, but there is none to be found on my laptop.

I am using blender 2.8.

If I press the install button as seen in the photo and the add-on disappears
[image: I press the install button as seen in the photo and the add-on disappears]

Comment: According to [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/unrealengine-blender-uebok-clipboard-copy-paste-and-export/1152327) you should've received a .zip, which you can install through *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons* by using the *Install* button. In your screenshot it look like it's a .rar though, not sure why that is the case. That being said, you don't need that add-on. You could export your model as .fbx or .gltf and import it into Unreal Engine.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for getting back to me. Sorry I should have included that I made a whole house and I want to export it so it all stays together. If I export it as an fbx, the whole house divides into parts and I have to resemble the whole thing. The rar file is the add on I received from a friend to hold the whole thing together..

Comment: Then you will have extract the .rar and add the add-on files to a .zip before you can install it through the preferences.

Comment: Even when the folder is zipped the add on will not install..:( I have tried a few.

Comment: I have also uninstalled and reinstalled blender

Comment: If you try to install the .zip is there any error message displayed? If yes please add it to your question

Comment: I just added the image of where the install in going to, you can see in the bottom corner it is installing somewhere but it is not showing up.  I cannot get into the user/library as I am on Mac. I tried putting code into terminal to display library but that didn't work. I also went into the package contents of blender by right clicking on the blender icon and there is no addons folder.. so I added python files to a python folder, and the zip file to the lib folder - still no luck..

Comment: Please post an image of the contents of the rar file. Do not try and install a file named `__init__.py` as addon.  If it is a custom addon it may be in the Testing category.

Answer (score 1):

When you download the BlenderTools.zip
extract it, and goto send2ue/addon which will contain folders like dependencies, functions, ui and some files.
select all the files & folders,
zip them & rename the folder to send2ue.
This can be installed as plugin in blender.

I know it's a late reply to this thread, but someone might find it useful. :)

A blessed guy made a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYfHZkPICxQ).